# Ruby and GTK3 without console window in background

Tags: ruby, windows, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

Hello Stackoverflow user's. this is my first question. :)

I'm using ruby and gtk3 to make a few GUI's for scripts that I use a lot. The problem I'm having is that when I run the script it opens the console window as well as the GUI, which in my mind defeats the purpose of a GUI.

I'm currently trying to run the scripts by executing them on my desktop.
I tried packaging it inside OCRA but that generated a lot of errors. I don't mind packaging or running the script directly as long as it doesn't open a console window, or at the very least closes it when it launches. 
I'm using windows, and ruby 2.0.x.

Basically I don't want a DOS console window to open when I run my script.

I'm intermediate with ruby so please, clear instructions and simple solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution. Save the script with .rbw extension instead of .rb extension.

Hopefully this will help other newbies.